# Saved checked items in listview and then repopulating the list showing checked and non checked

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I've desperately searched for a solution, and I know there is one out there with a really simple solution, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.  I'm populating a listview with the option to select multiple things.  I save the checked items in my database.  Where I am having issues is tyring to repopulate the listview at a different time, showing all the items and marking the previously selected items.  Any help would be great, thank you.

```
public class SelectIndustries extends Activity {

ListView mIndustryList;
Button mSaveButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.industry_list);



    mIndustryList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    mSaveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveIndustries);

    String[] industries = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.industries);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> industryArray = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, industries);

    mIndustryList.setAdapter(industryArray);

    mIndustryList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    mSaveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            SparseBooleanArray checked = mIndustryList.getCheckedItemPositions();

            for (int i = 0; i < mIndustryList.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
                if (checked.get(i)) {
                    String ind = industryArray.getItem(i);
                    InterestedIndustries t = new InterestedIndustries();
                    t.setACL(new ParseACL(ParseUser.getCurrentUser()));
                    t.put("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
                    t.setUser(ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
                    t.setIndustry(ind);
                    t.setIndustryPosition(i);
                    t.saveInBackground();
                }
            }

            Intent goToMain = new Intent(SelectIndustries.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(goToMain);

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: a for loop and [`setItemChecked(int position, boolean isChecked)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setItemChecked%28int,%20boolean%29) should do the job.

Comment: gotcha, then how would I go about updating my parse database if a user deslects something?  Also, thanks for the help with this.

Comment: when you restore the selection you have a list of the "original" positions currently stored in the database and then you have a "modified" list of positions when the user clicks the save button. Then you perform a basic set operation on those two lists, i.e `positionsToRemove = original - modified` and `positionsToAdd = modified - original`. Hint:  [`removeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29)